# Joining two mysql resultset using left outer join

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the actual invoice table

[image]

After grouping it based on invoiceID, the resultset is
[image]

And actual payment table is

[image]

and its payment resultset after grouping based on invoiceID is

[image]

Now i want to join these two resultsets [Payment and Invoice table] and find the balance amount subtracting Total from Amount based on InvoiceID and for non matching records the balance column should be zero. I tried this, but didn't get the expected result.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your want is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT  a.InvoiceID,
        a.totalSum InvoiceAmount,
        b.totalSum PaymentAmount,
        a.totalSum - COALESCE(b.totalSum, 0) TotalBalance
FROM
    (
        SELECT  InvoiceID, SUM(Total) totalSum
        FROM    InvoiceTB
        GROUP BY InvoiceID
    ) a LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT  InvoiceID, SUM(Total) totalSum
        FROM    paymentTB
        GROUP BY InvoiceID
    ) b
        ON a.InvoiceID = b.InvoiceID
```